# Pandas series replace value ignoring case but only if exact match

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, replace

As Title says, I'm looking for a perfect solution to replace exact string in a series ignoring case.

```
ls = {'CAT':'abc','DOG' : 'def','POT':'ety'}

d = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['cat','dog','pot','Truncate','HotDog','ShuPot'],'Result':['abc','def','ety','Truncate','HotDog','ShuPot']})
d
```

In the above code, ref hold the key-value pair where key is the existing value in a dataframe column and value is value to replace with.

Issue with this case is, service that pass the dictionary always holds dictionary key in upper case where dataframe might have value in lowercase.

expected output is stored in 'Result Column.

I tried including `re.ignore = True` which changes the last 2 values. 
following code but that is not working as expected. it also converting values to upper case from previous iteration.

```
for k,v in ls.items():
    print (k,v)
    d['Data'] = d['Data'].astype(str).str.upper().replace({k:v})
print (d)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapping series from the given dictionary, then transform the index of the mapping series to lower case, then using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) map the values in `Data` column to the values in mappings, then use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values in the mapped series:

```
mappings = pd.Series(ls)
mappings.index = mappings.index.str.lower()
d['Result'] = d['Data'].str.lower().map(mappings).fillna(d['Data'])
```

---

```
# print(d)

       Data    Result
0       cat       abc
1       dog       def
2       pot       ety
3  Truncate  Truncate
4    HotDog    HotDog
5    ShuPot    ShuPot
```